# using cat at input file

Tags: command-line, mysql, input

I have a file created with mysqldump that is 11GB. I need to use the "mysql" command to import it into a database, but I need to add:

```
USE db1;
```

at the top. It would take forever to rewrite the file. Is there a way I can  concatenate another file at the beginning of the input redirect to fool it into looking at it as a single file?

**text.txt** contents:

```
USE db1;
```

**sql_out.sql** contents:

```
data from mysqldump using the --skip-add-drop-table and --no-create-info options
```

command attempted:

```
mysql --host=<host> --user=<user> --password=<pwd> < echo $(cat text.txt sql_out.sql)
```

When I do that I get:

```
echo: No such file or directory
```

If I try it without the echo, I get:

```
$(cat text.txt sql_out.sql): ambiguous redirect
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you could just use the `-D db1` option to mysql, and redirect the contents of the sql file to the mysql command _without even using `cat`_. Ex:`mysql -host foo.io -u -p1234 yoda -D db1 < sql_out.sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe it in:

```
cat text.txt sql_out.sql | mysql --host=...
```

Alternatively, to avoid having to create a new file:

```
(echo "USE db1;"; cat sql_out.sql) | mysql --host=...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use process substitution here:

```
mysql --host=<host> --user=<user> --password=<pwd> < <(cat text.txt sql_out.sql)
```

the syntax `<(...)` treats a process's like a file

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing it. Thank you!